# Audio duration sometimes changes to near-zero in Safari

Tags: ios, macos, audio, safari

I am encountering a strange issue on Safari, both on MacOS and iOS. Initially it seemed like audio would sometimes just not play, but not emit any errors. After adding much logging I found that when when I call `audio.play()` the `audio.duration` property would accurately reflect the duration of the clip. The `pause` and then `ended` events will then almost immediately be emitted and, after that the duration for the same clip is suddenly somewhere between 0.001 and 0.003 seconds.

I am retaining a reference to the audio element and reusing it to play the same audio multiple times. It almost always works the first time, but after the first playthrough, on about 50% of subsequent plays the symptoms described above will present themselves.

The code where I play the audio is below:

```
    // In the constructor for the class managing audio playback:
    this.mediaElement.addEventListener('pause', e => {
        console.log('Media paused', this.mediaElement.duration); // This shows the very short duration if the audio did not play
    });

    // In the function in the class that plays the media.
    try {
        await this.mediaElement.play();
        console.log('Media is playing', this.mediaElement.duration); // This shows an accurate duration
        this.state = Playable.state.PLAYING;
    } catch(e) {
        console.error('Playing media failed:', e);
        if (e && e.name === 'NotAllowedError') {
            ErrorHandler.playbackNotAllowed(e);
            this.state = Playable.state.PAUSED;
            return;
        } else {
            this._fail(e);
            this._fakePlay();
        }
    }
```

As you can see, I'm not doing anything strange or complicated here. So far I haven't been able to figure out why the duration would change in this way only after playing the audio. Is this a known bug, or is there something I may be doing that could cause this behavior. The closest thing I can think of is that sometimes I will set the `currentTime` to 0 if I need to start playing the audio from the beginning, but that should not change the duration.

Comment: Any resolution on this issue? I'm experiencing the same.